# Find SCD-2 timerange overlaps when a sensor belongs to multiple labels simultaneously in SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, temporal

I have a PostgreSQL table that represents the time-bound associations of different sensors with different labels, using a [SCD-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) approach. The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SensorLabel (
    sensor_id INT,
    label_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
    end_time TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

Each row in this table represents that a sensor (sensor_id) is associated with a label (label_id) during a specific time period [start_time to end_time) (so, resp. inclusive, exclusive).

Now I have a problem where I need to find all time range overlaps for a set of labels. That is, I have a set of labels {label1, label2, ..., labelN} and I want to find all time ranges when the sensor was associated with each of these labels at the same time.

Please note that the time range for each label association could be different, so the intersection of these ranges may break up into smaller time-ranges. I want to return only those time-ranges during which the sensor is associated with all the given labels.

I can solve for say a static 2 labels or 3 labels but have problems wrapping this in a generic SQL that solves for a variable N labels

**EDIT**: some sample input and output

```
sensor|label|from|to
1|1|2021-01-01|2021-10-01
1|2|2020-12-01|2021-05-01
1|2|2021-07-01|2021-09-01
1|3|2021-03-01|2021-06-01
1|3|2021-08-01|2021-12-01
```

Ouput: i.e.: time-ranges where (time-ranges for) label 1,2,3, overlap:

```
sensor|from|to
1|2021-03-01|2021-05-01
1|2021-08-01|2021-09-01
```

Comment: could you please post some sample data and the desired output?  seems like you might need to derive a couple of columns, like 'association id'

Comment: why doesn't the time range start with label 1, i.e. 2021-01-01 ?  isn't sensor 1 associated with the label 1

Comment: @zhiguang, `label` is independent of `sensor`.

Comment: To your question add the Postgres version you are using.

Comment: How a label is is assigned to a sensor for a specific time-range is out-of-band is shouldn't matter afaik. Not sure if that is what you're asking. Specifically, why does the output timerange not start at 2021-01-01? Because label 3 only becomes active at 2021-03-01 so that's the first time timeranges for labels 1,2,3 overlap for sensor 1

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I'm using PG 14.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could do it is with a function:

```
CREATE TABLE sensorlabel (
    sensor_id INT,
    label_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
    end_time TIMESTAMPTZ
);

insert into sensorlabel values
(1,1,'2021-01-01','2021-10-01'),
(1,2,'2020-12-01','2021-05-01'),
(1,2,'2021-07-01','2021-09-01'),
(1,3,'2021-03-01','2021-06-01'),
(1,3,'2021-08-01','2021-12-01');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tsrange_fnc(l_ids integer[], s_id integer)
 RETURNS SETOF tstzrange
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE

    _tsrange tstzrange;
    _prevrange tstzrange := NULL;
    _testrange tstzrange;

BEGIN
for _tsrange in select
        tstzrange(start_time, end_time)
    from
        sensorlabel
    where
        label_id = ANY(l_ids)
    and
        sensor_id = s_id
    order by
        start_time  LOOP
    IF _prevrange IS NULL THEN
        _prevrange = _tsrange;
    ELSE
        _testrange = _tsrange * _prevrange;
        IF _testrange = 'empty'::tstzrange THEN
            RETURN NEXT _prevrange;
            _prevrange = _tsrange;
        ELSE
           _prevrange =  _tsrange * _prevrange;
        END IF;
    END IF;


END LOOP;
            RETURN NEXT _prevrange;
END;
$function$





select tsrange_fnc(ARRAY[1, 2, 3], 1);
                      tsrange_fnc                      
-------------------------------------------------------
 ["03/01/2021 00:00:00 PST","05/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")
 ["08/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT","09/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")

 select tsrange_fnc(ARRAY[1, 2], 1);
                      tsrange_fnc                      
-------------------------------------------------------
 ["01/01/2021 00:00:00 PST","05/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")
 ["07/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT","09/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")

select tsrange_fnc(ARRAY[2, 3], 1);
                      tsrange_fnc                      
-------------------------------------------------------
 ["03/01/2021 00:00:00 PST","05/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")
 ["08/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT","09/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT")
```

Comment: That is still pretty cool. Will look into it. Will leave open for a while to get other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping sensor label ranges can be found using a recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
sensor_labels(sensor_id, label_id, start_time, end_time) AS (
  VALUES (1, 1, '2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-10-01'::timestamp),
         (1, 2, '2020-12-01'::timestamp, '2021-05-01'::timestamp),
         (1, 2, '2021-07-01'::timestamp, '2021-09-01'::timestamp),
         (1, 3, '2021-03-01'::timestamp, '2021-06-01'::timestamp),
         (1, 3, '2021-08-01'::timestamp, '2021-12-01'::timestamp)),
labels AS (
  SELECT l.label_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY l.label_id) AS n
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) l(label_id)),
cte AS (
  SELECT sensor_labels.sensor_id,
         greatest(coalesce(time_span.start_time, sensor_labels.start_time), sensor_labels.start_time) AS start_time,
         least(coalesce(time_span.end_time, sensor_labels.end_time), sensor_labels.end_time) AS end_time,
         labels.n
    FROM labels
    JOIN sensor_labels
      USING (label_id)
    JOIN (VALUES (NULL::timestamp, NULL::timestamp)) time_span(start_time, end_time)
      ON (time_span.end_time IS NULL OR sensor_labels.start_time < time_span.end_time) AND
         (time_span.start_time IS NULL OR sensor_labels IS NULL OR time_span.start_time < sensor_labels.end_time)
    WHERE labels.n = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sensor_labels.sensor_id,
         greatest(cte.start_time, sensor_labels.start_time) AS start_time,
         least(cte.end_time, sensor_labels.end_time) AS end_time,
         labels.n
    FROM labels
    JOIN sensor_labels
      USING (label_id)
    JOIN cte
      ON labels.n = cte.n + 1 AND
         (cte.end_time IS NULL OR sensor_labels.start_time < cte.end_time) AND
         (sensor_labels.end_time IS NULL OR cte.start_time < sensor_labels.end_time))
SELECT cte.sensor_id, cte.start_time, cte.end_time
  FROM cte
  WHERE cte.n = (SELECT max(labels.n) FROM labels)
  ORDER BY cte.start_time, cte.sensor_id;
```

This query works by iterating over the labels to refine the overlapping times. This query assumes that `start_time`/`end_time` pairs define closed-open intervals, `sensor_labels` have non-NULL `start_time`, and NULL `end_time` means until the end of time. The initialization portion of the CTE includes `time_span` which can be used to efficiently limit the selected range of times. A `NULL` for either indicates that the corresponding bound is unconstrained.